# JsonMappingException in Binary data type deserialization in java

Tags: java, binary, deserialization, webclient, thrift

I have the following structures defined in thrift.

```
struct ResponseBody {
  1: binary payload                
  2: string text           
}

struct Response {
  1: string header
  2: ResponseBody body
}
```

When i try to deserialize to Response class, I am getting following exception

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Conflicting setter definitions for property "payload": com.project.thrift.kaushik.ResponseBody#setPayload(1 params) vs com.project.thrift.kaushik.ResponseBody#setPayload(1 params)
```

Since thrift is generating two setters in generated java file

```
setPayload(byte[] payload) and setPayload(ByteBuffer payload)
```

I tried with Jackson 2.9

```
Json.decodeValue(response, Response.class)
```

Comment: did you find any solution here?